# C++ - how to forward declare a class in the same file as main() - getting variable uses undefined class error

Tags: c++, class

I'm aware of using function prototypes, and I was under the impression that forward class declarations could serve a similar purpose when `main()` and a class are in the same file.  For example, I would have expected this would compile:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

// class prototypes
class MyClass;

int main(void)
{
  MyClass myClass;

  // do stuff with myClass here

  return(0);
}

class MyClass
{
public:
  int someInt;
  double someDouble;

  // more stuff here . . .

};
```

But on the `MyClass myClass;` line I'm getting the error `'myClass' uses undefined class 'MyClass'`.  What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm aware that I could cut/paste `main()` below all the classes it uses and that would fix the error, but I'd prefer to keep main() as the first function or class.

P.P.S. I'm aware that in any substantial size production program `main()`, `.h` content, and `.cpp` content would be in 3 separate files.  In this case I'm attempting to write a small example or test program where main and a class(es) are in the same file.

Comment: A forward declaration doesn't tell the compiler what size the object will have, which means that when compiling your `main()`, the compiler cannot know how much space to reserve on the stack for the object `myClass`.  Therefore to instantiate an object you need to have the full class-definition already parsed before the place where you do the instantiation.

Comment: so there is absolutely no way to make this work other than to put main() at the end of the file ?

Comment: why do you think you need that?

Comment: @cdahms No, there's absolutely no way.

Comment: erm... "Every other modern language supports this" - no. "I hope in the next C++ revision this is added." - quite unlikely. Btw if you think you can add something to the answer or you think it needs a summary, then better write an answer, questions are for questions ;)

Comment: There is an option that may not have been mentioned (depending on how you read other content here): You only need to provide the class declaration before `main()` - I.e. what member variables and functions the class has. The definition of the member functions can follow after `main()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declarations can only be used via pointers or references.
Calling a constructor function doesn't fall into this category.

---

> I'm aware that I could cut/paste main() below all the classes it uses and that would fix the error, but I'd prefer to keep main() as the first function or class.

That's why usually header files are used, instead of placing all the declarations and definitions in the `main.cpp` file.

> I'm aware that in any substantial size production program main(), .h content, and .cpp content would be in 3 separate files. In this case I'm attempting to write a small example or test program where main and a class(es) are in the same file.

You should still stick to that idiom though, everything else would probably end up in a mess.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use forward declarations but it partially addresses the spirit of a single main.cpp with your "main" at the top. I find this technique sometimes useful when you want to share something via an online C++ ide where a single file is much easier to deal with, and you want to focus on the action in main rather than implementation detail in helper structs/classes etc.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename MyClass,typename MyOtherClass>
int main_()
{
  MyClass a;
  a.do_foo();
  MyOtherClass b;
  b.do_bar();
  return 0;
}

struct MyClass
{
  void do_foo() { std::cout << "MyClass: do_foo called\n"; }
};

struct MyOtherClass
{
  void do_bar() { std::cout << "MyOtherClass: do_bar called\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  return main_<MyClass,MyOtherClass>();
}
```